# How do I change the "About Me" of the Area 51-discussion profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, area-51

I've recently changed the 'about me' of [my profile at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/142143/pandya) but the [Area 51-discussion profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/142143/pandya?tab=profile) is till showing old and I can’t find any option to edit it.

So, how do I change the "About Me" of the [area51-discussion profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/142143/pandya?tab=profile)?

Later, I found my [Area 51-discussion profile updated](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/142143/pandya?tab=profile) but don't know how. I thought it requires considerable time to be synced with Area 51 profile. But [some have said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272195/how-do-i-change-the-about-me-of-area51-discussion-profile#comment883441_272195) it is not synced even after year, some said it is network-wide. so I was not sure about how actually it works. Finally I concluded as answer

Comment: Looks like you can't. Going to the profile page and clicking Edit takes you to A51 again; Settings doesn't link anywhere interesting; URL-hacking silently redirects. I last changed my A51 profile description probably a year ago, but it hasn't synched, so I think it's just flat-out busted. Retag as bug.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've just [checked](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/142143/pandya?tab=profile) and found it changed! I don't know how did it change!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is concluded that Area 51-discussion profile synchronises with Area 51 profile but it requires considerable time to be synchronized.

**So, you don't need to change your Area 51-discussion profile separately. Just change your Area 51 profile and the Area 51-discussion profile will be automatically synchronized.**

Note: An Area 51-discuss profile is similar to a meta site for Area 51. You can't (and don't need to) change your meta profile separately for each site because it synchronizes with your main profile. The same thing goes to Area 51 and Area 51-discussion. The difference is only for Area 51-discussion, it takes more time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to wait for the meta page to sync up with your main account.

Here is how, after editing your profile on the main Area51.SE go to the [Area51.meta] and click the "Ask Question" button it should instantly update your meta profile.

[What is it about the "Ask Question" button that makes it update my Area51.meta profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317604)

Comment: Nice workaround, Lol! :)