# What is it about the "Ask Question" button that makes it update my Area51.meta profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, area-51, caching

In Area 51, if my main profile gets some form of update, like an avatar or reputation change, I have to wait a while for my Discussions profile to update (sync) due to caching.

However, I can just simply click the "Ask Question" button on Discussions, and it updates instantly. **I have tried this many times, and it always works.**

Is there anything special about that button that makes my profile update when clicked?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just assigning correlation to two unrelated events that happened at around the same time?

Comment: I upvote, because this user asks a question, and it's not a reason to punish him by downvoting.

Comment: @Quidam we vote based on content, not based on who posted it. As such my down vote is not punishment. Please stop misrepresenting what votes mean on SE.

Comment: On the "normal"  sites there is a known lag between main and meta (I guess similar as you see on Area 51). As Area 51 is on an older code base it can have either quirks or hidden features that short-circuit the reputation sync. I can totally imagine this is a left-over that only exists in Area 51. Now we need to wait if there is a dev that is willing to take a look at that spaghetti. I wouldn't have high hopes ;)

Comment: I now get what you're saying. Retracted my vote; am about to edit.

Comment: @RobertLongson I now get what the author is saying; if you voted to close, please retract it.

Comment: @rene I've edited it so it's clear now.