# How to get the Autobiographer badge in Area 51-discussion / Area 51 meta

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, area-51, per-site-meta

I signed up on Area 51 and filled out my profile there to get the Autobiographer badge, which [also worked](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/209950/fcdt?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_badges). It was only later that I came across the *Area 51 Discussion Zone* ([Area 51-discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/)) and had to find out that I had not received the badge there, which is why I edited my profile (at Area 51) again (yesterday).

In *[How do I change the “About Me” of the Area 51-discussion profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272195/how-do-i-change-the-about-me-of-area51-discussion-profile)* it was written that I have to wait a while before the profile is also adopted in Area 51-discussion. It was then adopted, but I did not receive the badge. I haven't had this problem with any other meta-site.

In *[How have more people edited their profiles on main sites than on per-site metas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333208/how-have-more-people-edited-their-profiles-on-main-sites-than-on-per-site-metas)* it was mentioned that my Area 51-discussion-profile was only created when I visited this page for the first time. Could it be because of that and can I still get the badge? According to the [badge overview](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer), other people have already received the badge.

(In the overview there is also [this user](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/189880/david-wisniewski) who received the badge yesterday at Area 51-discussion, but he did not fill out his profile and did not get it on Area 51, which also looks like a bug.)

Comment: The joy of Area-51 ... its ever aging code-base never let us down in doing or not doing amazing things ....

Comment: FYI: There is a recent [complaint about the Autobiographer badge not being awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353640/282094) that is tagged [tag:status-review] - because Area 51 uses a different code base I'm not suggesting that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Rob Thanks. I ran the database query mentioned in the post but area51 and area51-meta are not listed there. So I also think it's a different mechanism.